# Auto height container with inline divs in a using float an

Tags: css

If I have a container, with several nested divs :

```
<div class="beat-container" id="beat-container-1"> 
  <div id="1-1">
    <div class="beat" id="beat-1-1">
      I am a beat View<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="1-2">
    <div class="beat" id="beat-1-0">
      I am a beat View<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="1-3">
    <div class="beat" id="beat-1-0">
      I am a beat View<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I use float on all but the last child, I get the functionality I need, where they are side by side.  Adding `float:left` to the final one prevents the enclosing parent container from wrapping all the children, and it loses its height.

If I add it to all them, then try to add a `:last-child` it still doesn't work.
How do I get the divs to be inline, and have the parent border still wrap them.
The container height should be dynamic, so no specific height attributes or JS.

CSS:

```
.beat-container {
  border: 1px solid orange;  
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.beat {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  float: left;
}
.beat :last-child {
  float: none;
}

/* .beat :not(:last-child) {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  float: left;    
} */
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g3L3w/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your questions correctly.

You can add overflow: auto; to .beat-container then it will wrap the content.

```
.beat-container {
  border: 1px solid orange;  
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;

  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g3L3w/2/

If you want to use the last-child selector to target the last div with .beat you have to target the parent of .beat as all .beat are both first-child and last-child of the parent in your current structure. 
e.g. .beat-container > div:last-child > .beat 
You can go with a less qualified selector for your example but in a bigger context it would probably be what you want.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g3L3w/4/